# Como fazer para ao checar uma checkbox ela mude a cor de fundo de uma td de uma tabela e ao deschecar ela retorne para sua cor normal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Bom, eu tenho este código, e ele funciona em partes, quando eu checo a checkbox ele muda a cor da minha td, porém ao deschecar a cor não retorna ao normal, alguém poderia me ajudar? Desde já agradeço.

```js
 $('.checkbox-regularC').click(function(){
     $('.linhaCdSRotinaTurma').css('background-color','#fff');
     $('.linhaCdSRotinaTurma').css('cursor','auto');
 })
```

```css
.linhaCdSRotinaTurma {

    background-color: #cccc;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    border: 0px;

}
```

```html
 <div class="caixaSelectsTodasCategorias">
     <div class="caixaCheckBoxTodasCategorias">
         <div class="selecionarTodos">
             <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-regularC"> 
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 
 <table class="tabelaNovaRotinaSelects" id="table_rotina_default">
     <thead>
         <tr id="rotinasDefault">
             <td class='tituloCdSRotinaTurma'>
                 Titulo
             </td>                        
         </tr>
     </thead>  
     <tbody>
         <tr class="linhaCdSRotinaTurma">
             <td>Alternativas</td>      
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Vai ser só uma ou são várias na mesma tela?

Comment: Vai ter apenas uma tr uma linha, né porém com várias colunas

Comment: Newton, como você é usuário novo, dá uma lida neste link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour para saber o que fazer ao fazer perguntas e receber respostas. Abs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o checkbox está checado para assim fazer a ação que deseja:

```
$('.checkbox-regularC').click(function(){
    if ($('.checkbox-regularC').is(':checked')) {
        $('.linhaCdSRotinaTurma').css('background-color','#fff');
        $('.linhaCdSRotinaTurma').css('cursor','auto');
    } else {
        //voltar a cor ao normal
    }
});
```

Comment: Moça, funcionou não

Comment: Perdão, erro de sintaxe ali na hora de fechar o click, fiz a correção ali.

Comment: Qualquer coisa tu dá um console.log($('.checkbox-regularC').is(':checked'));

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de fazer isso usando um objeto com os estilos.

Você verifica se está checado com `$(this).is(":checked")`, que retorna **true** (se estiver checado) ou **false** (caso não esteja checado).

O objeto `opts` possui uma função com os estilos entre chaves `{}` que retorna os valores dependendo do valor no parâmetro `i` da função, alternando as propriedades usando ternários (**[saiba mais sobre operador ternário](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operador_Condicional)**).

Uma das vantagens do ternário é evitar repetição de código quando se quer pegar um valor ou outro baseando-se numa condicional. Exemplo:

```
// se i for true, a cor será #fff, caso contrário será #ccc
i ? '#fff' : '#ccc'
```

Definindo estilos entre chaves `{}` usando `.css`:

O seu código pode ser simplificado. Você está usando `.css` para o mesmo elemento duas vezes:

```
$('.linhaCdSRotinaTurma').css('background-color','#fff');
$('.linhaCdSRotinaTurma').css('cursor','auto');
```

Usando as chaves `{}`, você pode definir múltiplas propriedades num bloco só, sem que seja necessário repetir o mesmo elemento:

```
$('.linhaCdSRotinaTurma').css({
   'background-color':'#fff',
   'cursor':'auto'
});
```

A diferença é que neste formato você deve separar os valores com dois-pontos `:` em vez de vírgula.

Outra coisa há se notar é que você pode escrever os nomes das propriedades fora das aspas, mas caso haja um hífen `-`, você deve removê-lo e escrever a primeira letra após em maiúsculo:

```
'background-color' -> backgroundColor
```

Exemplo:

```
$('.linhaCdSRotinaTurma').css({
   backgroundColor:'#fff',
   cursor:'auto'
});
```

**Veja o código em funcionamento:**

```js
$('.checkbox-regularC').click(function(){
   var opts = function(i){
      return {
         'background-color': i ? '#fff' : '#ccc',
         'cursor': i ? 'auto' : 'not-allowed'
      };
   }
    
   $('.linhaCdSRotinaTurma')
   .css(opts($(this).is(":checked")));
});
```

```css
.linhaCdSRotinaTurma {

    background-color: #cccc;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    border: 0px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caixaSelectsTodasCategorias">
   <div class="caixaCheckBoxTodasCategorias">
      <div class="selecionarTodos">
         <input type="checkbox" class='checkbox-regularC'> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<table class="tabelaNovaRotinaSelects" id="table_rotina_default">
   <thead>
      <tr id="rotinasDefault">
         <td class='tituloCdSRotinaTurma'>
            Titulo
         </td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="linhaCdSRotinaTurma">
         <td >Alternativas</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma classe CSS específica para quando o checkbox estiver marcado, também, e aplicar nas tags HTML de acordo com o estado do checkbox.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.checkbox-regularC').on('change', function() {
    var classes =
      $(this).is(':checked') ? 
        ['linhaCdSRotinaTurma','linhaCdSRotinaTurmaMarcada'] :
        ['linhaCdSRotinaTurmaMarcada','linhaCdSRotinaTurma'];

      $('.' + classes[0]).addClass(classes[1]).removeClass(classes[0]);
  });
});
```

```css
.linhaCdSRotinaTurmaMarcada {
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: auto;
}

.linhaCdSRotinaTurma {
    background-color: #cccc;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caixaSelectsTodasCategorias">
    <div class="caixaCheckBoxTodasCategorias">
        <div class="selecionarTodos">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-regularC"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 
<table class="tabelaNovaRotinaSelects" id="table_rotina_default">
    <thead>
        <tr id="rotinasDefault">
            <td class='tituloCdSRotinaTurma'>
                Titulo
            </td>                        
        </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
        <tr class="linhaCdSRotinaTurma">
            <td>Alternativas</td>      
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```